# Understanding locally sensitive hashing

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hash-function

I recently studied about locally sensitive hashing an a follow explanation was given to me.

To produce a hash for a particular vector X with dimensions 5,

Draw 10 random vectors to form a plane and perform a dot product with the vector X.

In other words, a 10 x 5 matrix will be dot product with vector X.

The hash can be given as 1 if the result of each element in the resulting vector is positive else 0.

However, am i supposed to understand that these matrix can be considered a plane and how does it actually mean that if the dot product is negative/positive, it determines which side of the plane the vector is one?

Does the 10 random vectors form a subspace hence a plane?

Anyone can explain this? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the paragraph "The hash can be given..." is stating. Surely you don't want a hash function to only produce two possible values, $0$ or $1$. In my answer I suppose you are talking about individual bits of the hash code, but your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_{10}$ be the random vectors. For each $p_i$, it defines a hyperplane whose normal vector is $p_i$; that is, the hyperplane partitions $\mathbb{R}^5$ into two parts, namely, $$\{v \in \mathbb{R}^5 \mid p_i^Tv > 0\}\quad \text{and}\quad\{v \in \mathbb{R}^5 \mid p_i^Tv \leq 0\}$$

Therefore, LSH function maps $x$ to $1$ if and only if
$$
x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{10} \{v \in \mathbb{R}^5 \mid p_i^Tv > 0\}
$$
As you can see, it is actually not a hyperplane in general.

Comment: If my vector v is always positive, does it mean that my p must be always drawn from a distribution that may give me negative values ?

Comment: @aceminer Theoretically it is. It depends on what metrics you are using. For Euclidean distance, a vector drawn from normal distribution is usually used.

Comment: How does Euclidean distance come into picture here if you are measuring dot product? Sorry I am missing it

Comment: @aceminer Moreover, as stated by Marc, it seems that you misunderstand the LSH function.

Comment: @aceminer For Euclidean distance, the LSH function is usually defined as $$ h(x) = \lfloor \frac{a^Tx + b}{w} \rfloor$$ where $w$ is a fixed value called "width", $b \sim \mathsf{uniform}(0, w)$ and each entry of $a$ is independently sampled from a normal distribution. In this way, we have $$\Pr(h(x) = h(y)) > \Pr(h(x) = h(z))$$ if $\|x - y\| < \|x - z\|$.

Comment: hey thanks! Can you explain the last line on probability in greater detail. I think your answer is great but I am still missing something at the last line which I feel it lies the gist

Comment: @aceminer This is the intuition of LSH. LSH was originally proposed for nearest neighbor search; that is, given a query $q$, we want to find an object in a set $\mathcal{D}$ such that the object is closest to $q$ in $\mathcal{D}$. LSH guarantees that if two objects $x$ and $y$ are close, they will collide (i.e., $h(x) = h(y)$) with high probability; and if they are distant, they will collide with low probability. More specifically, the probability is a non-increasing function of distance.

Comment: So am I right to say the function that you suggested satisfies this intuition?

Comment: @aceminer Yes for this case. Please also note that there are many LSHs, designed for different types of distances.

Comment: For the function you proposed. It satisfies the Euclidean distance because it's the absolute distance between 2 vectors?

Comment: @aceminer We do not say "a LSH function satisfies a distance".. If you are interested in this, you'd better refer to this paper (http://www.mlpack.org/papers/lsh.pdf) for more details, including the intuition.

Answer (score 1):

No, your vectors do not form a subspace.

I think the idea is to get a $10$-bit hash value from your $X$ by computing the $10$ bits independently, each one by looking at the sign of one particular nonzero linear form on your vector space. If $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ designate the coordinates of your vector space, a linear form is an expression of the form $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4+ex_5$ for some constant scalars $a,b,c,d,e$, in other words if it the value obtained by applying a one-line matrix $\pmatrix{a&b&c&d&e}$ to your vector$~X$ (as a column vector). The value of that expression is a number, so to get a bit from it just only look whether the value is positive.

This linear form (if it is not entirely zero, which of course you will choose) takes the value $0$ on a hyperplane of your space, in other words on a $4$-dimensional subspace. The bit you obtained by applying the linear form tells you on which side of this hyperplane your vector lies (the linear form make one side "positive" and the other side "negative"; the point of the hyperplane itself are consider as"positive"). Now if you apply a matrix with $10$ rows, then you get $10$ bits, each telling you on which side of a different hyperplane your vector is. If you have chosen your rows not to badly, then these hyperplanes chop you space into $2^{10}$ "chambers", and your hash code tells you in which of these chambers your vector$~X$ lies.

Comment: Yes I understand. But geometrically or mathematically why is this idea feasible? Like how can I prove that it is a lsh?